# How to connect Android to liferay database

Tags: android, liferay

I am developing an android application and I need to connect to my liferay portal and retrieve some data from it.
How can I connect to that database from android application?

thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect Android app to liferay portal. Please follow the below URLS.

[Connect Android to Liferay Step by Step](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/using-the-android-sdk-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-08-en)

[Include Liferay in Android](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/using-custom-portlet-services-in-your-an-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-08-en)

Comment: Can I use it with liferay 6.0.6 ?

Comment: No, liferay mobile sdk support started from 6.2. It mentioned in official liferay documentation https://www.liferay.com/en_GB/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/mobile-sdk-to-call-services-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-en.